# How can I access Windows Forms element via variable in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am developing program which is *verrrry* tiresome.
Like

```
Private Sub AccessElement(Code1 as integer)
    Select Case Code1
       Case 1
         Me.Btn1.Text = "Do it"
       Case 2
         Me.Btn2.Text = "Do it"
 ...
    End Select
End Sub
```

I want to access elements like this:

```
Private Sub AccessElement(Code1 as integer)  
Me.(Code1.ToString()).Text = "Do it"
End Sub
```

How can I do like this?

Comment: You can use `Me.Controls("Something")`  when the control is direct child of the form, or  `Me.Controls.Find("Something", True).FirstOrDefault()` when the control is not a direct child and is in a panel or something.

Comment: It worked! Thank you